# Turning Off a Program When the other one closes .Bat file

Tags: batch-file

This is my code so far ive tested it and both programs open when .bat is run , What im after is the code to close program 2 when program 1 closes any help would be appriciated as i have no coding knowledge :(

```
@echo off
start "TestFolder" "C:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder\test1.exe" %1
start "Testfolder2" "C:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder2\test2.exe"
taskkill /f /im test2.exe
exit
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to setup a `FOR /F` Loop to monitor the output of `TaskList` to check for the window title of the 2nd program (and you'll need to explicitly set the window title of that program to something unique to do that.)

Then you will need to use `Taskkill` to kill the other task.

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  echo off )

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B )

:Main
  start "TestFolder1" "C:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder\test1.exe" %1
  start "Testfolder2" "C:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder2\test2.exe"
  CALL :Loop
  taskkill /f /im test2.exe
GOTO :EOF

:loop
  SET /A "n=10"
  TIMEOUT 10
  tasklist /V /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq test1.exe" | FIND /I "TestFolder1" &&(
    GOTO :loop
  )
GOTO :EOF
```